# What are some good iPad apps for students?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, software-recommendation, productivity

I am mainly looking for apps which help increasing productivity and not the ones like Calculator, Periodic Table etc.

Apps which are good for taking notes, taking handwriting input.

Comment: This question is extremely broad. Could you please specify in more detail what you are looking for, which real world situations you are aiming to solve and at which solutions you've already looked (and why you did or don't like them)?

Comment: made it more specific.

Comment: Thanks for coming back but this is still rather generic. What will you do with the result, are you writing an article about choices, are you too busy to search yourself, are you just curious? There are tons of applications out there, what would they need to include to make them of special use for students (compared to business people for instance)?

Comment: I'd say, if you explored and detailed in writing the problem you face - people can offer apps, or processes to use the built in apps to solve that problem.

Comment: I just got myself an iPad Air and I was looking for some useful apps. I found [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/what-are-some-great-ipad-apps?rq=1) but it has hardly any apps which would be helpful for a student or someone who is in academia. So I started this thread to know some good apps which can be of help to students. This question may be too broad or opinion based (like the other one), however it will help a lot of people.

Comment: Questions suitable for this site have concrete answers. "What app do you recommend to solve this particular problem?" is a single question with possible concrete answers. "What are some good apps for productivity?" is a great lead into a conversation, but not a concrete question for this site. The fact that your description of what you are looking for ends in "etc." and doesn't have a closed form is a good indicator that you are asking too broad a question. Your last comment is telling: this is supposed to be a **question**, not the start of a **thread**. That's why it's closed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I would like to know how my question is different from [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/what-are-some-great-ipad-apps?rq=1) If I edit and say the question as 'What are some best iPad apps for students?' Will that be accepted?

Comment: There is quite a lot of overlap between your question and the linked one, so any student will find helpful apps by looking there. "what are the best ..." type questions have always been kind of controversial on AD (and on StackExchange in general), there are several discussions on the meta site about it already.

Answer (score 3):

- [CourseNotes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coursenotes/id364183278?mt=8)
- [inclass](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/inclass/id374986430?mt=8) (Free)
- [iThoughtsHD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ithoughtshd-mindmapping/id369020033?mt=8)
- [GoodReader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8)
- [Evernote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8) (Free)
- [iStudiez Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istudiez-pro/id310636441?mt=8)
- [istudiez lite](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/istudiez-lite/id322439186?mt=8) (Free)
- [Papers](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/papers/id304655618?mt=8)
- [Timeli](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timeli/id386890857?mt=8)
- [Pomodoro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pomodoro-app-for-ipad/id393490589?mt=8)
- [Dictionary.com – Dictionary and Thesaurus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dictionary.com-dictionary/id364740856?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) (Free)
- [Merck PTE HD](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/merck-pte-hd/id375734631?mt=8) (Free)
- [Inkling](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inkling/id379351586?mt=8) (Free)
- [Dropbox](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8) (Free)
- [OmniFocus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/omnifocus-for-ipad/id383804552?mt=8)
- [Notes Plus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notes-plus-handwriting-note/id374211477?mt=8)
- [Articles](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/articles-for-ipad/id364881979?mt=8)
- [Articles for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/articles-for-iphone/id317065689?mt=8) (Free)
- [Multiponk](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multipong/id366322908?mt=8)

The above are some of the most essential ipad apps helping productivity for students.
For more details see [here](http://ipad.appstorm.net/roundups/productivity-roundups/15-essential-ipad-apps-for-students/).

Comment: nice list there! It would be more useful if you mention which all of them are free.

Comment: @avi, updated the list with which all of them are free.

Answer (score 0):

[Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/):

- Allows you to learn almost anything for free.
- [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/khan-academy/id469863705) is the best way to view Khan Academy’s complete library of over 4,200 videos.

See also:

[Khan Academy - Youtube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy).

This blog entitled ["Apps in Education](http://appsineducation.blogspot.co.uk/)" also contains a wealth of information that may assist you.

[Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/):

Is a free reference manager and academic social network that can help you organize your research, collaborate with others online, and discover the latest research.

The [iOS App](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mendeley-reference-manager/id380669300?mt=8) allows you to carry thousands of PDFs in your pocket. Read and annotate them on the go, search your entire library, and easily sync everything between your iPhone, iPad, and Mendeley Desktop (available on Windows, Mac, and Linux).